# Harfbuzz selection local slash char in font file

Tags: unicode, fonts, opentype, freetype2, harfbuzz

I have a system font called MyriadHebrew-Regular.otf

I was using "slash" char (code 47)  but then I noticed that the one which
used by Adobe After Effects is a little bit different .Then I inspected 
the font in the FontCreator program and found that it is possible to use default char (47) ,
or localized version of it (appears as slash.1), which is located at the end of the font glyph maps.Its glyph index is 587.
So I have been trying to access the localized glyph with Harfbuzz:

```
.......
 hb_buffer_t *m_hb_buffer = NULL;
 hb_font_t *m_hb_font = NULL;
 std::wstring str = L"שתץףך /";
 const wchar_t* text = str.data();
 hb_buffer_t *m_hb_buffer = hb_buffer_create();
 hb_buffer_set_direction(m_hb_buffer, HB_DIRECTION_RTL);
 hb_buffer_set_script(m_hb_buffer, HB_SCRIPT_HEBREW);
 hb_buffer_set_language(m_hb_buffer, hb_language_from_string("he", 2));
 hb_buffer_add_utf16(m_hb_buffer, (uint16_t*)text, -1, 0, -1);
 hb_feature_t ft;
 hb_feature_from_string("locl",-1, &ft); // ft.tag = 1819239276; ft.value = 1
 hb_shape(m_hb_font, m_hb_buffer,&ft, 1);
 hb_glyph_info_t *m_info = hb_buffer_get_glyph_infos(m_hb_buffer, NULL);
 FT_UInt glyph_index = m_info[0].codepoint; // glyph_index = 400 instead of localized glyph_index=587
.......
```

In this code I expected that glyph_index = 587 (local one like in Adobe aftereffect) but instead it is still 400 (standard one).

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this problem it needs addition feature "aalt" that allows to do substitution:

..............................

```
hb_feature_t ft[2];
hb_feature_from_string("aalt", -1, &ft[0]);
hb_feature_from_string("loca",-1, &ft[1]);
hb_shape(m_hb_font, m_hb_buffer,(const hb_feature_t*)&ft[0], 2);
```

............................

Comment: As this is an AALT glyph, does it still need to have the localised language `he` set? Or is it independent of the language in use?